# RODBC odbcDriverConnect() Connection Error in shiny R but not in Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc

I'm trying to use

```
odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL 
Server};server=IP;database=DBNAME;uid=username;pwd=password")
```

to connecting sql server database from shiny R,
but its result is -1.
I run the same code in R studio and get results normally, what's the problem?

For testing more I tried this one:

```
 con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
             Driver = "SQL Server",
             Server = "IP",
             Database = "dbname",
             UID = "username",
             PWD ="password",
             Port = Port)
```

But again it runs in R studio but not in shiny and gets this error:

```
 nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: IM002: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name 
 not found, and no default driver specified
```

Comment: It may be running into the network's firewall: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217592507-How-do-I-give-my-application-on-shinyapps-io-access-to-my-remote-database-

Comment: Where is the shiny code executed, on a server? If yes the server may lack the required ODBC driver (which is difficult to install on Linux). For a good description of the ODBC installation see e. g.: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/